# Apache 500 Internal Server Error when authenticating with authz_svn_module with an empty user name field

Tags: apache-2.2, active-directory, svn

**My Environment**

- Apache 2.2
- Windows Server 2008 R2 (I also had the same problem with Windows 7)
- Tortoise SVN  1.8.7 Subversion 1.8.9

I have this SVN Server using Apache for authentication with Active Directory using authz_svn_module and its dependencies(mod_dav_svn.so, etc.). The authentication part works fine normally, but if I leave the field **User Name** empty, it generates a 500 Internal Server Error.

The problem happens either if I try to log from a web browser or if I try to perform an **svn checkout.**

It does not generate an entry in the Apache **logs/error.log** file, but it leaves an entry in the **logs/access.log** file:

```
x.x.x.x - "" [12/Aug/2014:11:00:10 -0300] "GET /svn/ HTTP/1.1" 500 550
```

as opposed to when I type an invalid user/password:

```
x.x.x.x - invalidu1  [12/Aug/2014:10:11:03 -0300] "GET /svn/ HTTP/1.1" 401 401
```

I also noticed that the 500 error comes from my AD server instead of from 127.0.0.1. There is a Linux server performing authentication for its SVN server against the same AD server and it does not have this problem.

Is this a known bug? If not, is there a way that I can validate empty username fields before they go for authentication?

My httpd.conf SVN entry looks like this:

```
    
    DAV svn

    SVNPath G:/mypath/to/svn/
    SVNIndexXSLT "/svnindex.xsl"
    AuthType Basic
    AuthBasicProvider ldap file



    AuthzSVNAccessFile G:\svn\svn_projects_permissions

    # The name of the protected area or "realm"
    AuthName "SVN Projects"


    # Active Directory requires an authenticating DN to access records

    AuthLDAPBindDN "CN=a,OU=b,OU=c,OU=d,DC=e,DC=f,DC=com"

    # This is the password for the AuthLDAPBindDN user in Active Directory


    AuthLDAPBindPassword "abcdefgijkl"

    # The LDAP query URL

    # AuthLDAPURL "ldap://abcdef.gh.com/OU=COLAB,DC=c,DC=com?sAMAccountName?sub?(objectClass=*)"

    AuthLDAPURL "ldap://123.45.678.29/OU=abc,OU=dfe,DC=ghij,DC=ab-group,DC=com?sAMAccountName?sub?(objectClass=*)"

    Require valid-user

    AuthUserFile "G:\svn\svn_projects_passwords"
```

Comment: see http://serverfault.com/a/569467/145724 set `AuthLDAPBindAuthoritative off`